# upload a single image to firebase storage

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I'm using ionic and I wanted my app to pick an image from my android device then upload it to my firebase storage. I have a function called getter which will trigger an image pick event. 
I already installed cordova image picker and added the service. 
[image]

but when I run it it says illegal constructor.

Or is there other way to convert it to a file type?

What should I do here?

Comment: Post actual code...not images of code. Nobody can copy anything from image to change anything. Also provide full error details. See [ask] and [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist?s=2|1.1852)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve it by using the image URL from Storage